# Integrating RGB image and nDSM data

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, remote-sensing, fusion

How can I integrate RGB image and nDSM data provided in the dataset (ISPRS Vaihingen) that I want to use in a multimodal deep learning based semantic segmentation method? Can anybody provide a Python code to do so.

The below code provides a way to make semantic segmentation only from RGB images.

https://github.com/nshaud/DeepNetsForEO/blob/master/SegNet_PyTorch_v2.ipynb

But how the data preprocessing has to be done to make the fusion of RGB and nDSM data both to make the segmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pretrained weights, such as those used in the example, you cannot just add another band / layer of information. This is because the pretrained weights are made for standard RGB imagery and does not work with four layers of input.

As such, you have two options:

1. Drop the pretrained weights
2. Reduce your dimensions from four to three. Options are dropping a band or doing something like a PCA to drop reduce.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I’ll try to implement it in that way then.

Comment: Do remember to accept or upvote answers, @SoumyaGhosal